# communication theory bounds on codes

Tags: combinatorics

For a binary code,

given that $A(4,3) \leq 2$, Show that $A(5,3) \leq 4$.

I have tried using the Hamming Bound but this produces a higher bound than $4$.

I am assuming that assuming that increasing the length of the code by 1 then the number of possible codes will double, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: Please could you provide a little more detail, in particular the definition of $A$ ?

Comment: A(n,d) is the largest M such that there exists an (n,M,d) code.  An (n,d)-code is optimal if it has a size A(n,d).

Comment: (n,d) is a linear binary code of length n and minimum hamming distance d

Comment: So the question is, assuming that subspaces of $F_2^4$ having minimum Hamming distance $3$ must be at most $2$- dimensional, prove that subspaces of $F_2^5$ having minimum Hamming distance $3$ must be at most $4$- dimensional ?

Comment: That is correct thank you for helping to clarify the question

Comment: Hm. Actually I think I may have misunderstood. Is $A$ the dimension of a linear code, as I've assumed, or is it the number of codewords in a code that need not be linear ?

Comment: I think we are indeed talking about codes that need not be linear. In which case I have a proof. If you like, I can post it as an answer, but if you would prefer to keep trying to figure it out, then here is a hint: Suppose, for a contradiction, that you have a set of 5 vectors in $F_2^5$ whose minimum Hamming distance is $3$. By the Pigeonhole principle, there must be (at least) $3$ of them that have the same first digit.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could post the answer, i like where you are going with the pidgeon hole principle, the bit i am struggling with is the link to A(4,3). I can prove that A(5,3)<4 by allocating codes into bins that include sets of codes that have a hamming distance of 2 or less and counting the number of bins, assuming that there must be a maximum of 1 code from from each bin and i have 4 bins i get to the answer but it doesn't include A(4,3). Your answer would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'll make some assumptions which I hope more knowledgable people will correct, if they're wrong:

$A(n,d)$ is the size of the largest possible set of vectors in $F_2^n$ such that the minimum Hamming distance between any pair of them (that is, the number of coordinate positions in which they disagree) is equal to $d$.

Suppose, for a contradiction, that there exist $5$ vectors in $F_2^5$ such that the minimum Hamming distance between any pair of them is $3$.

Our goal will be to choose $3$ of these $5$ such that $2$ of them are Hamming distance $3$ apart, and all $3$ vectors agree in some coordinate:

Of those five vectors, let $u$ and $v$ be two that are Hamming distance $3$ apart from each other. Then $u$ and $v$ must agree in $2$ coordinate positions, say, in the $i$-th and $j$-th coordinate positions, where $i \neq j$.

CASE I:
At least one of the other $3$ vectors also agrees with $u$ and $v$ in the $i$-th position, or in the $j$-th position, in which case we have what we asked for.

CASE II:
The other $3$ vectors, $x, y$ and $z$, all disagree with $u$ and $v$ in the $i$-th position and in the $j$-th position. Therefore they must all agree with each other in the $i$-th and $j$-th positions. Therefore their Hamming distances apart from each other must be at most $3$, hence exactly $3$. Now $x, y$ and $z$ are $3$ vectors such as we asked for.

In either case, we have $3$ vectors, $2$ of which are Hamming distance $3$ apart from each other, and all of which agree with each other in some coordinate. Delete that coordinate to obtain $3$ vectors in $F_2^4$. These must be distinct, since the original $3$ vectors in $F_2^5$ disagreed with each other in more than one coordinate.

Moreover, since we deleted a coordinate in which all $3$ vectors agreed, the $3$ vectors in $F_2^4$ must have pairwise Hamming distances the same as before we deleted that coordinate. In particular, we have $3$ vectors whose minimum pairwise Hamming distance is $3$, which contradicts our assumption that $A(4,3) \leq 2$.

Conclude that we were wrong to suppose that there exist $5$ vectors in $F_2^5$ such that the minimum Hamming distance between any pair of them is $3$. Therefore, $A(5,3) \leq 4$.